# How to make a simple docker service accessible from external hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

First, I inform you that i'm currently student in software development. So I beg for your tolerance regards to my question.

I'm dockerising one of my java web application. It's working fine on my Windows 10 host, connecting in localhost.
But I need to make my web application accessible from other hosts, like I would do in a real life scenario.

**[EDIT]:** in this post [docker-compose assign lan ip to service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599074/docker-compose-assign-lan-ip-to-service), they use some network config in docker-compose.yml. But as I said, I don't understand it enough to adapt it to my case :/

Currently, I can access my web app only from the host running the docker containers, with this url : "http://localhost:8080/public/showAtlas"

What I would like is my web app to be accessible in any browser with an url like : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/public/showAtlas" where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is a public IP adress that I could define in the dockerfile or docker-compose.yml

Is that possible with few config lines or is it tricky?
I guess many will want to tag my question as duplicate, but I didn't find any simple answer to this simple usecase.

Could someone please help me to get this working?

I looked many online resources but the solutions are too "complex" for me to adapt it to my case.

**Dockerfile of my springboot app:**

```
FROM store/oracle/serverjre:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD webapp/output/webapp.jar webapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "webapp.jar"]
```

**Dockerfile of my database:**

```
FROM postgres:latest
COPY db_wtc.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

**My docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    db-wtc:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
        container_name: cont-db-wtc
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/postgres/data
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        expose:
            - 5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: admin_wtc
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
            POSTGRES_DB: db_wtc
        networks:
            - wtc-network

    wtc:
        depends_on:
            - db-wtc
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: cont-wtc
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        expose:
            - 8080
        environment:
            SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin_wtc
            SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 123
            SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db-wtc:5432/db_wtc
        networks:
            - wtc-network

networks:
    wtc-network:

volumes:
  db_data:
```

No particular error. I just can't access my docker service from any external host.

Thank you guys very mush for your time!

Comment: You should be able to use your host’s IP address and the published ports (the first number in `8080:8080`).  Docker has no way to assign additional reachable IP addresses or DNS names to your host.

Comment: Try adding `EXPOSE 8080` in your Dockerfile

Comment: @JSingh I already tried this but didn't has any effect.
That being said, if it should be ok from other host with my "IP adress", which IP are we talking about? The public one?

Comment: Try accessing with your local IP address ¿the other host is in the same network?

Comment: If you use your home computer, no one can access your services by default. You had to play with your network settings on your machine AND your modem/router.

Comment: Why not rent a small node on linode or digital ocean for like 5 bugs a month?  You still should take your time to secure it but In my opinion better than exposing your private network.

Comment: @TheFool I am using my personal laptop, with a wirless connection to my internet router. You mean I need configure it in order to kinda authorize the access to my host through the IP adress?

Comment: I guess I will rent a small cheap server, but the pb will be the same. I will need to configure it so the external access work. And of course just want to get it work on my laptop for few seconds. It just for a project in my degree. Not to stay active.

Comment: @JohnStudent exaclty this is your issue. The public internet cannot simly access your "home" ip. You need to configure the modem to allow this. Thats why I suggest to rent a virutal mini server. I wrote this stack script to spin up a docker-compose node on linode, a couple month ago https://gist.github.com/bluebrown/d76597ae57d3348af227d117c14fd4c2 . You still need to secure it though! And no, on a server like this which is not a home network, you don't have to do the "same" configuration. It's accesible from the getgo, but not secure.

Comment: @TheFool, I will try it tomorow then! Hope it will be easier :) Your post will help I guess ! I will keep you posted of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I derive from the comments, this is not a docker-compose issue! The problem is that you want to access your "home" network from the public internet wich is not possible by default. You need to configure your modem to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be using tunneling. If you are not trying to deploy for production try using ngrok. (https://ngrok.com/)

All you have to do is install ngrok and run

```
$ ngrok http 8080
```

And it will provide you with an address that you can use temporarily.

Comment: Nice. Gona try this too tomorow! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it was just a problem due to my home network.
I rent a vps and it worked like a charm, using the IP of the vps.
I didn't need to change anything in the above docker files.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Maybe I am hustling for points here but I think you should not accept your own answer after someone told you and you just repeat. Accept your own answer when no one tells you and you have to figure out the hard way.

Comment: Oh no pb. I just did it so that the question is mark as answered. Didn't think for a sec about "competition" aspects...